# Why am I getting Null Reference Exception inspite of checking if the Object is not null to execute something

Tags: unity, collision-detection, collider

Hi I am just trying to convert a simple flappy bird game into multiplayer game.

So In the multiplayer game using Photon , I want the bird to collide with the ground or pipe but not with the enemy bird .i.e., ignore the enemy's bird collision. I somehow worked it out,code below.

So I have tagged the bird under a name called "BirdClass" , and in the start I have the following code to ignore the coillision for the first time:

```
void Start()
    {
       PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        playerBird = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("BirdClass");
        if (playerBird != null)
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(playerBird.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>());

    }
```

Over here I get the following error:

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: collider1
UnityEngine.Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (UnityEngine.Collider2D collider1, UnityEngine.Collider2D collider2) (at <4e5075cf57c3416eb788a8bd41817a84>:0)
BirdPigeon.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/BirdPigeon.cs:45)

and the onCollider2d function looks like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        playerBird = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("BirdClass");
        if (isMultiPlayerGame && playerBird != null && PV.IsMine)
        {           
           if (collision.gameObject.tag == playerBird.gameObject.tag)
            {
                Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>());
            }
            else
            {
                BirdCollided?.Invoke(true);             
            }
        }
        if (!isMultiPlayerGame)
        {
            BirdCollided?.Invoke(true);
            rigidBodyOfBird.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
```

and here I get the error like:

```
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
BirdPigeon.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision) (at Assets/Scripts/BirdPigeon.cs:81)"
```

I can't understand, though I am checking whether it is null or not ,why I am still getting these errors?

Comment: If you want to ignore bird collision with other players, the easier way is to use the physics layer https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: @Zibelas thank u so much, this helped . Initially it didnt work because it was under Physics I unchecked, but later when I did it under Physics 2D it work...Cheeers mate

Answer (score 1):

It appears like your "playerBird" game object has no component of type `Collider2D`. Make sure that one of the 2D colliders is attached. When you want to find it via `GetComponent`, then it must be attached to the object directly. When the collider is attached to a sub-object of the "playerBird", use `GetComponentInChildren` instead.

Also keep in mind that there are also colliders which do not have the suffix "2D". These are 3D colliders used by the 3D physics engine. 2D and 3D colliders are completely separate systems and do not interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not fixing your nullpointers, it will have the same result in the end. You are trying to solve a collision exception manually. Good for you that Unity ships this with a simple collision matrix. If you are using 2D physics, you need to use the 2D version.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `playerBird` is not null, but apparently does not have `Collider2D` attached, hence this call:

`playerBird.GetComponent<Collider2D>()` returns null

Comment: This has been mentioned in another answer; why do you feel the need to repeat it?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I added information that entire function call to `GetComponent` returns null which must be checked indepedently of `playerBird` which may be not null